# Hide Labels from pandas.cut customised Interval Index

Tags: pandas

I applied pandas.cut on Series. if I don't use customised Interval Index, `label=False` works as expected (returns only integer indicators of the bins). However, when I used customised Interval Index, even I set `label=False`, it returns interval of each bin. I guess this is probably because I used interval index in stead of number of bins.

Is there anyway to use customised interval index, also only return integer indicator of the bins?

```
bins = pd.interval_range(start=0, end=10, periods=5, closed='left')
pd.cut([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], bins, labels=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `codes` attribute

```
pd.cut([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], bins, labels=False).codes

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int8)
```

The `pd.cut` function returns a `Categorical` type object.  What gets displayed are the various categories for each element.  However, the `Categorical` object has two attributes `codes` and `categories`. The `categories` are what you'd think.  It is an array of your unique categories in the proper order.  The `codes` are the positions of that `categories` array that each element of the `Categorical` object is referencing.

You can produce the `Categorical` values by slicing the `categories` array with the `codes` array like so:

```
mycut = pd.cut([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], bins, labels=False)

mycut.categories[mycut.codes]

IntervalIndex([[0, 2), [2, 4), [4, 6), [6, 8), [8, 10)],
              closed='left',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

However, the `codes` are the exact thing you were looking for... so take it.

Comment: thank you! Can you please explain what does the codes attribute do ? I googled it but cannot find useful information

Comment: @Osca I updated my answer with more explanation.